# Alter color in Picture class in grImport

Tags: r, grimport

I found a terrific package `grImport` for reading in .ps files (vector vs. raster).  It works very well and the reader can find the package info here:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/grImport/grImport.pdf

and a demo here:

https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/grImport/import.pdf

I'd like to be able to change the color of slots in an object of the class `Picture` but can not figure out how.  So using this code:

```
library(grImport); library(grid)
## Create a generic .ps file to read in
postscript("foo.ps")
plot.new()
text(.5, 0.5, "A", cex = 45)
dev.off()  

## read in the .ps object
PostScriptTrace("foo.ps")
foo <- readPicture("foo.ps.xml")
grid.picture(foo)
```

How can I alter the object `foo` to make the `A` plot as a light grey, say `#D0D0D0`?

I tried:

```
class(foo)
foo
foo@rgb
```

I assume this is an S4 object which may be why I am struggling (I lack familiarity with s4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str` to explore the structure of the S4 object:

```
R> str(foo)
Formal class 'Picture' [package "grImport"] with 2 slots
  ..@ paths  :List of 1
  .. ..$ text:Formal class 'PictureText' [package "grImport"] with 14 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ string   : Named chr "A"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "string"
  .. .. .. ..@ w        : num 3602
  .. .. .. ..@ h        : num 5400
  .. .. .. ..@ bbox     : num [1:4] 904 2644 4840 6154
  .. .. .. ..@ angle    : num 90
  .. .. .. ..@ letters  :List of 1

  ...
```

The color can be changed in the following way:

```
foo@paths$text@letters$path@rgb <- "#D0D0D0"
```

Comment: Perfect I get it.  It's a mix of s4 slots and lists.

Comment: How would you do it if the object has multiple paths? I tried setting it in an lapply or loop, but no avail!